# What is the effect (or purpose) of a foreign key column referencing itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sybase

During a database migration, I've run across a database table constraint of the form:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT [someName] FOREIGN KEY ([id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[myTable] ([id])
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Why would one do this? This was originally done on a Sybase database, and we are converting to SQL Server 2008 R2.

**UPDATE**: Yes, the foreign key constraint is a field referencing the same table AND SAME FIELD.

I ran this query on the source Sybase database and found 42 of these crazy keys defined, so it doesn't seem like a typo.

```
SELECT sr.constrid as [Constraint ID],
       so.name as [Table],
       sc.name as [Column]
  FROM sysreferences sr
       INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON (so.id = sr.tableid)
       INNER JOIN syscolumns sc ON (sc.id = sr.tableid AND sc.colid = sr.fokey1)
 WHERE sr.tableid = sr.reftabid
   AND sr.fokey1 = sr.refkey1
   AND sr.fokey2 = 0
   AND sr.refkey2 = 0
```

Comment: So... `id` is a foreign key to itself.  Does this even work?  You can't add an `id` until it already exists.  I can understand if `id` referenced a different column in the same table for a tree-like structure.

Comment: I guess that's a mistake. Is there another column which has "id" in it? Maybe it was intended to be a hierarchy table (id/parent_id) and the constraint was incorrectly specified by mistake

Comment: Are you sure is not something like `FOREIGN KEY ([parent_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[myTable] ([id])`?

Comment: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42), you say?

Comment: Can you use TRUNCATE TABLE in Sybase if it has a self-referencing foreign key? Maybe it was a way to prevent a table truncation?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that hierarchies are the standard examples you'll find in books whenever you use foreign keys for the same table, such as:

```
create table Employees (
 EmployeeID int identity primary key,
 EmployeeName varchar(50),
 ManagerID int
 Foreign key (managerID) references Employees(EmployeeID)
)
```

What you posted looks like a wrong application of this hierarchy relation in the same table. I'm not entirely sure why you'd ever wanna do that.

Hope this helped =)

Comment: I agree with you completely, however, none of the 42 tables in question have ancestor-like columns in them, nor do any of these tables have anything remotely to do with a hierarchical relationship.

Answer (score 1):

**Surprise!** This totally works:

```
create table crazy (
    ID int primary key references crazy (ID) -- This runs
);
insert into crazy select 1;  -- So does this
select * from crazy; -- Returns 1
truncate table crazy; -- Works just fine
```

I can only think that this would have been a mistake (Typo? Dragging a column onto itself in a diagram?) or used to fool another system (ORM?) into some particular behavior.  I will be *very* curious to see if someone comes up with a legit reason.

UPDATE: As cleverly suggested by @8kb, this could have been an attempt to prevent truncation, but we can see from my example that even truncation works just fine.

Comment: As noted in my updated post, I doubt it is a typo.  No ORM is in use on this particular application.  Very, very strange.

Comment: Is there anything common or any pattern to these 42 tables or the columns on which these self-referencing keys apply?

Comment: None I can see at first blush.  The columns have different data types (some integer, some character).  The tables have no tight semantic relationships or programmatic relationships.  The only commonality I can see is that all of those tables were created by the same contracting firm many years ago.

Comment: Though I did not ever find out a legit reason, I think I did find out the real reason why these strange foreign keys were created.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

**I guess it's a bug in database model.**

It's really weird. I can't imagine what usefull purpose is this construction.

The only way how to insert data is without checking reference integrity. It means with explicitly disabled references or with some kind of bulk insert and so on.

Comment: My first thought was also something along the path of preventing inserts or deletes on the tables.  But, @Tim Lehner demonstrated that you can insert data just fine into a table with this type of constraint on it, and the application has been inserting data into these tables for years without issue.

Comment: So, the database engine propably ignore this reference. However its still is weird AND now we know, its most propably useless :).

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a foreign key column referencing itself *seems* to be nothing.  It is still an outstanding question as to why a database engine would let you do such a useless thing.

However, I believe the **reason** someone would build a foreign key like this is laziness / carelessness.  I found out that in SQL Server Management Studio, if you build a foreign key using the GUI (instead of writing it out in T-SQL), the initial behavior of SSMS is to create foreign key exactly like in this question:

1. Expand any table of a database in the Object Explorer pane.  We will call this table TableA.
2. Rt-click on Keys under the TableA node and select New Foreign Key...  This will open the Modify table pane and the Foreign Key Relationships dialog.
3. Changing nothing, simply click the Close button on the Foreign Key Relationships dialog.  *"Oops, I didn't mean to try to add a foreign key."*
4. Closing the dialog still generated a foreign key with the name FK_TableA_TableA and picked the primary key column as both the base and reference column.
5. With the Modify table pane still open (which it still is after closing the Foreign Key Relationships dialog), close it.  It has changes (the new foreign key you just made).  Save these changes.
6. A new foreign key now exists in the database for TableA, with the primary key column referencing itself.